# Django istartswith performance

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, indexing

I have a model with column "name" and I am running query with istartswith and I am using postgresql. I have added `django.db.models.Index` with Postgresql opclass

```
Index(fields=('name',), name="partial_name_pat_idx", opclasses=("varchar_pattern_ops",),
 condition=Q(published=True))
```

But I can't figure out how do make I make use of index for case insensitive search, I have tried with django model function `Upper('name')` but it is not supported in `fields` argument. If I pass `Upper(F('name'))` in expressions django is restricting me to use `opclasses=("varchar_pattern_ops",)`. Is there any way I can create index for queries with `LIKE` operator and `UPPER` function on field name?

Answer (score 0):

If `name` is the index field you want a case insensitive search on, I'd suggest one of 2 things.

1. Store all data in `name` as upper or lower from the start, so you know the exact format. You could specifically define a field type for this.

```
class LowerCaseCharField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return str(value).lower()
```

2. Add a case insensitive index to the table (worse for performance, but probably not really noticable unless your table is really huge anyway).

```
class Meta:
    indexes = [
        Index(
            Upper('name'),
            name='name_case_insensitive_idx',
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: In option no 2, the index won't be used for like queries?

Comment: Postgres does a whole lot of optimisation behind the scenes. If you add an index, then do a case insensitve filter on name, it will almost certainly optimise to use that index. Try it and then do an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the query it generates to see ...